# Perforce Scripted Installer

Tags: installation, perforce

I was trying to create a scripted installer for P4V. 
The port settings, user setting and the workspace name are set as specified in the config file.
But when I open perforce the connection dialog box throws an error "client 'manojpc' unknown".
The following was my configuration file:

set P4PORT=server:2345
set INSTMODE=NoPrompt
set INSTTYPE=ClientOnly
set P4ROOT=$(SystemDrive)\My Depot
set CLNTEXES=$(SystemDrive)\Perforce
set P4USER=username
set p4CLIENT=$(HOSTNAME)

 
If I specify an already existing workspace, perforce won't allow me to use it in a PC other than the one from which it was created.
So how do I make this work?
Please let me also know if the above settings will set the "C:\My Depot" as the workspace dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Workspace settings, make the **Host:** field blank.  This will allow you to use the same workspace from any computer.

Comment: Keep in mind, anytime I've used a workspace across multiple computers, I've always done it on a network folder (NFS specifically).  I've never done such a workspace in which the root directory was local to the computer, so I'm not sure how this would work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you possibly need to use the `p4 client` command to set up a workspace before-hand?
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.061/manuals/cmdref/client.html#1040665

Comment: When I try to use the p4 client command, "Can't create a new user - over licence quota" error is thrown. But I am trying to create a workspace right?

Comment: I was using P4V and thats the reason those commands were not working. using P4Win solves the problem. But why does not P4V recogonise those commands?